# Any ideal as an intersection of ideals primary to maximal ones

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, primary-decomposition

The Nullstellensatz says that any ideal $I \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ has the property that

$\sqrt{I} = \bigcap_{\text{maximal } \mathfrak{m} \supset I} \mathfrak{m}$

Is it also true that we can write any ideal as above as

$I = \bigcap_{\text{maximal } \mathfrak{m} \supset I} \mathfrak{q}_{\mathfrak{m}}$

for certain $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideals $\mathfrak{q}_{\mathfrak{m}}$? Note that I'm only allowing a single primary ideal for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$; if I allowed countably many then the problem would be trivial.

I suppose my question applies to any Jacobson ring instead of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ .

Comment: I am probably not understanding the question correctly. But as far as I can see it is true vacuously because the maximal ideals themselves are primary. Please correct me if I am mistaken